# Need some clarification on the Gremlins “after midnight” rule

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, gremlins

In the first *Gremlins* (1984) film, the buyers are instructed to not feed him (Mogwai) after midnight.

What does “after midnight” mean exactly? What if they give Mogwai food at 6:00 MA or 7:00 AM? How long “after midnight” is it OK to feed him again?

And what if Mogwai was on a plane being fed while traveling from one time zone to another? What do you think would happen?

Comment: Isn't the second question from *Gremlins 2*?

Comment: @Walt  I haven't seen gremlins 2, only 1

Comment: Oh, OK. I'm just asking because it's almost like a direct quote. ;) A person that didn't believe Billy taunted him and said: *"What if they're in an airplane and they cross a time zone? It's always midnight somewhere."* [There was no reply, though.]

Comment: BTW, as for Q1, I'm assuming it ends at dawn, since it's no longer nighttime.

Comment: @Walt, I would agree with this, but further add that dawn is not always the exact same time every day of the year. So, perhaps that's why an end time is never given. Because it's different depending on the time of the year.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two explanations.

The first possibility, and most likely (in my opinion), is that this is a convenient theatrical construct to convey the creepiest or most dangerous time of the day – where it’s dark, cold, and things go bump in the night. There is always plenty of time for those who wander in the darkness to do their bidding. This is unlike just before dawn where one can be optimistic of coming light. And yes, I agree that with the coming of dawn, the period of risk is over until the approach of the next midnight.

The second possibility is to apply a little science. Assuming a day is exactly 24 hours, midnight is when you are 180 degrees longitude away from noon on the other side of Earth. Where it’s “high noon”, the sun is at zenith – the highest point in the sky. And this “line” of high noon moves around the Earth as it rotates on its axis. So, a gremlin would somehow have to know that it is “at opposite” to noon. That is the only non-fantastical answer. It also answers the question of whether you cross time zones. It doesn’t matter what time zone you are in and whether you are crossing time zones.

Comment: Third possibility: "after midnight" ends when they go to sleep.

Comment: @detly Sounds good to me.

Comment: Of course, astronomical midnight isn't the same as midnight according to the time zone you're in...